# Powermock avoid PrepareForTest to run class to be mocked

Tags: java, rest, testing, powermock

I need your help with PowerMock and some REST Testing.

I want to test a REST GET all, which is returning data from a database via a different package. Therefor, the REST method calls a executionService.getData();

```
@Path("interface/more/path/") 
public class RestConnection {
    [..]
    @GET
    @Path("path/{ID}/")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response showDetails(@PathParam("ID") int ID) {
         if (something == 0) {
         LinkedList<Integer> scenarioIDs = executionService.getData();
         [..]
```

which calls a method from a different package for the lookup.

```
    public class ExecutionService {
    [..]
          public LinkedList<Integer> getData() {
                return dbLookup.getDataIDs(); //which makes a lookup in MySql
          }
```

In my test i want to mockup getData() so that i doesnt perform the db lookup rather just return a pre prepared linkedlist which is json encoded with the rest and returned.

```
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*","java.sql.*","com.mysql.jdbc.*"})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ExecutionService.class)
public class RestConnectionTest {

    private ExecutionService executionService = new ExecutionService();

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ExecutionService executionService = PowerMock.createPartialMock(ExecutionService.class,
                "getData");
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetScenarios() {
        suppress(constructor(Connection.class));
        String getUrl = "/interface/more/path/path/0/";

        try {
            //PowerMock.mockStatic(ExecutionService.class);
           // PowerMock.replay(ExecutionService.class);
            PowerMock.expectPrivate(executionService, "getData").andAnswer(new IAnswer<LinkedList>() {
                @Override
                public LinkedList answer() throws Throwable {
                    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();
                    ll.add(1);
                    ll.add(2);
                    ll.add(3);
                    return (ll);
                }
            });
            //PowerMock.verify(ExecutionService.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        get(getUrl).
                then().
                assertThat().
                body(
                        matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("json/schema.json")

               );

    }
```

now.. somehow i get a

```
IllegalStateException - no last call on a mock available
```

Error and a

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

Error. Further it seems, that PowerMock executes the original getData() method which tries to connect to the database. And that fails also. Could you help me with that?

Thanks!

Comment: add `Powermock.replayAll()` at the end of your mocking

Comment: thanks Vihar, that doesnt solve the issue :(

Comment: Experiencing the same issue... Did you fixed it somehow?